# WCF service is adding extra word 'Field' to attributes

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3

WCF service is adding extra word 'Field' to attributes. I tried adding System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute() but still it adds 'Field' to the attributes. Is there a way i can fix this?

```
  [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml",  
          "4.0.30319.233")]
  [System.SerializableAttribute()]
  [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
  [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute()]
  public partial class Employer
  {

      private string nameField;

      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "Name")]
      public string Name
      {
         get
         {
            return this.nameField;
         }
         set
         {
            this.nameField= value;
         }
      }
```

Comment: Adding it where--in the contract? Because your model appears to be exempt the suffix.

Comment: Yes, it is adding it in the auto-generated contract.

Comment: What is really the problem that you encounter that you say you want to fix it by not having the Field suffix?

Comment: yes. I don't want the Field suffix

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Interface file in the WCF project, and you should prevent it.

```
  public interface IService
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContract] 
        string GetData(int value);
     }
```